# AWS S3Client throws error: 'emitWarning' is not a function

Tags: node.js, runtime-error, aws-sdk-js, mongodb-realm, aws-sdk-js-v3

I am trying to create an S3Client using the `@aws-sdk/client-s3` package, as shown below:

```js
const { S3Client } = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3')
const client = new S3Client({ region: 'us-east-1' })
```

It runs fine locally, but when I upload the code to a MongoDB Realm function along with the client-s3 dependency, it throws the error: `{"message":"'emitWarning' is not a function","name":"TypeError"}`

What might be causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was happening because the MongoDB Realm Functions environment does not have an `emitWarning` function defined on the global `process` variable, which is why the error kept saying `'emitWarning' is not a function`.

I reached out to MongoDB Support about this, and apparently the AWS-SDK v3 just isn't compatible with MongoDB Realm Functions.

Instead, you must use the AWS-SDK v2. I eventually found this [MongoDB Forums Article](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/aws-sdk-inside-realm-function/123937), which explained that they specifically support v2.737.0 of the SDK.